# How could I send keys to input tag by using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to send some text to an `input` tag by using the following code, but failed. I think I followed the guide from the official doc[1](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html), so couldn't figure out why nothing happens. Could anyone please have a look at the code? Any advice is appreciated.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def search(driver):
    driver.get('https://www.logseq.com')
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Open a local folder").click()
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("k").perform()
    search_bar = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("input.cp__palette-input")
    search_bar.send_keys("abc")
   
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    search(driver)
```

Comment: `.find_element_by_tag_name("input.cp__palette-input")` should be `.find_element_by_css_selector('input.cp__palette-input')` ?

Comment: @frianH, I did try both, and both give me the right input element, but could not send text to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.execute_script` method, like below:

```
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.cp__palette-input')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'abc';", search_bar)
```

Comment: this works perfect! Could you please elaborate that why my code does not work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's javascript effect. Please see [this link](https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-execute-javascript/) or [this](https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html#2) @Leu_Grady